# ajax Calls from IOS Safari many times ultra slow

Tags: jquery, ajax, safari

I have the problem that ajax-calls (with jQuery) on my iphone safari (on same wlan). They are ultra slow. When i test it via Desktop (firefox, chrome) there is no problem. The ajax calls take about 80ms. My IOS device is sometimes fast too, but most times it needs more than 5000ms for the same call.

I could understand, when IOS needs 200ms, but 5000ms are def. showing that something is wrong. SO i testet it with IOS Chrome. Its the same issue like IOS Safari.

Does somebody else has the same problem? I have no ideas, how i can check (debug) the calls for analyzing.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem on one of my projects and currently investigating. My app relies heavily on async resource loading and it sometimes makes the entire thing halt because it is waiting for a response. Have you had any luck in your research?